# Archivos del formato .V_SF

Tags: android, programación-móvil, arquitectura

Instale una app juego para android llamado ***"Hidden City"*** con el fin de ver como estaba construido, resoluciones de imágenes, etc ...

*Aclaro: No quería robar nada, solo quería estudiar como lo habían hecho, ya que me encanta su diseño y me gustaría hacer algo parecido.*

Despues del instalar al app, voy a las carpetas de data android, busco la carpeta donde se instalo el juego y me encuentro con 9 archivos con extension **.V_SF**

*Por ejemplo:* `icons_retina.v_sf`

*Investigando sobre el origen de estos archivos no encontré nada, pero había información sobre .vsf (sin guion bajo)*

**1. Unos dicen que son archivos index con todas las direcciones a los recursos alojados en un una nube.**

**2. Otros dicen que son archivos encriptados por una empresa llamada Voltage Security, Inc**

Mi pregunta es como seria la arquitectura de esa aplicación, ya que no tiene recursos en mi celular como imágenes/audios/textos?

¿ De donde levanta el código `java`, `css` y todas las cosas que necesita para funcionar bien ?

Si alguien sabe algo sobre el tema, cualquier link para leer/investigar son bienvenidos. Gracias.